# Creating dataframe from tempfile

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to load a temporary file into a pandas dataframe and throwing an error.  Not sure how to get the parsed data from the temp file into a dataframe to use later on.

```
line = []
for x in readMe:
    line.append(" ".join(x.split()))
 with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
    for i in line:
        " ".join(i.split(None))
        temp.write("%s\n" % i)
    df = pd.read_csv(temp.name, sep=' ', names=curves, skiprows=dataStart, header=None)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/LAS Load.py", line 42, in 
...
       return func(*args, **kwargs) 
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to prepend 'file://' to temp.name. After un-indenting the `df` assignment by two tab stops. The `i.split(None)` is odd, it seems just like `[i]`, and `' '.join([i])` has no side effects. Maybe another copy-n-paste hiccup?

Comment: You recently un-indented by a single tab stop, so now we see `for` and `df =` under the `with`. The trouble with this is that you really want to exit the `with` first, so it has a chance to `close()` the temp file descriptor, before attempting to `read_csv()` that file.

Comment: I believe the tempfile will be deleted and inaccessable to anything outside of it's with statement?

Comment: Alternatively, you might pass in the open `temp` descriptor instead of `temp.name`. Not sure if you need to `fseek` to the front of it first.

Comment: Oh. I guess I usually make up '/tmp/foo' names on my own. Yes, you're right, it will be gone and inaccessible. So my concern is whether the `write()` is buffered at all, do we want to flush or close?

Comment: I considered that route.  However the program errors before I can get that far, it throws an error on line 42 which is the "temp.write("%s\n" % i)" command

Comment: Oh. Your traceback obscured that, I thought read_csv was throwing. Ok, I'll take another stab at it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us what `readMe` contains, in particular what type it causes `i` to have. If possible, would you please run this under python3? If not, show us some details like `type(i)`, and do a trivial `temp.write('hello')` so it's clear the file descriptor is writable. It's still not obvious what side effects line 41 has:

```
        " ".join(i.split(None))
```

The '%s' % i is essentially taking str(i). Perhaps what we're looking for is `i.encode('utf8')`, or passing in a [temp file encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html).